# PayPal Subscriptions API with PHP and JS SDKs - RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND Error

Tags: php, paypal

I was working in paypal subscription process with JS SDK . First of all i have created the plan successfully by PHP SDK And activated it . Then i was trying to implement the subscription process with JS SDK by that plan ID. But some how its not working . If anyone can help me out that will be great.

**This is my code:**

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        env: 'sandbox',
        createSubscription: function (data, actions) {

            return actions.subscription.create({

                'plan_id': 'P-15T61220BN038602UZQLZ2UI',

            });
        }
        ,
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {

            alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

**This is the error :**

> Uncaught Error: Create Subscription Api response error:

```
{
    "name": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The specified resource does not exist.",
    "debug_id": "f2628efbed424",
    "details": [
        {
            "issue": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
            "description": "Requested resource ID was not found."
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

**My Plan API CODE :**

```
use PayPal\Api\ChargeModel;
use PayPal\Api\Currency;
use PayPal\Api\MerchantPreferences;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentDefinition;
use PayPal\Api\Plan;
use PayPal\Api\Patch;
use PayPal\Api\PatchRequest;
use PayPal\Common\PayPalModel;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require "app/config.php";

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        'AbMJNJRtMOefeVPE9UM50...........', // ClientID
        'EN8kxO-TjQb_Lr..........'     // ClientSecret
        )
);


//$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential('AbMJNJRtMOefeV........', 'EN8kxO-TjQb_LrcpSdYGRoXz5LX6HmJyQ4lC---------'));
//if (! empty($_POST["subscribe"])) {
//    require_once "./Service/createPHPTutorialSubscriptionPlan.php";
//}
// Create a new billing plan
$plan = new Plan();
$plan->setName('Family plan monthly fathomreads')
        ->setDescription('Famaliy plan monthly')
        ->setType('INFINITE');

// Set billing plan definitions
$paymentDefinition = new PaymentDefinition();
$paymentDefinition->setName('Regular Payments')
        ->setType('REGULAR')
        ->setFrequency('Month')
        ->setFrequencyInterval('2')
        ->setCycles('0')
        ->setAmount(new Currency(array('value' => 6.60, 'currency' => 'USD')));

//// Set charge models
//$chargeModel = new ChargeModel();
//$chargeModel->setType('SHIPPING')
//  ->setAmount(new Currency(array('value' => 10, 'currency' => 'USD')));
//$paymentDefinition->setChargeModels(array($chargeModel));
// Set merchant preferences
$merchantPreferences = new MerchantPreferences();
$merchantPreferences->setReturnUrl('http://localhost/fathomreads/paypalsuccess.php')
        ->setCancelUrl('http://localhost/fathomreads/paypalcancel.php')
        ->setAutoBillAmount('yes')
        ->setInitialFailAmountAction('CONTINUE')
        ->setMaxFailAttempts('0')
        ->setSetupFee(new Currency(array('value' => 0, 'currency' => 'USD')));

$plan->setPaymentDefinitions(array($paymentDefinition));
$plan->setMerchantPreferences($merchantPreferences);
//create plan

try {
    $createdPlan = $plan->create($apiContext);

    try {
        $patch = new Patch();
        $value = new PayPalModel('{"state":"ACTIVE"}');
        $patch->setOp('replace')
                ->setPath('/')
                ->setValue($value);
        $patchRequest = new PatchRequest();
        $patchRequest->addPatch($patch);
        $createdPlan->update($patchRequest, $apiContext);
        $plan = Plan::get($createdPlan->getId(), $apiContext);

        //Output plan id

        dbQuery("UPDATE general_settings SET paypal_subscription_planid = '" . $plan->getId() . "' WHERE id = 1 ");



        echo "Plan created Successfuly. Plan Id : " . $plan->getId();
    } catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getCode();
        echo $ex->getData();
        die($ex);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die($ex);
    }
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getCode();
    echo $ex->getData();
    die($ex);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    die($ex);
}
```

**The RESPONSE :**

Plan created Successfuly. Plan Id : P-15T61220BN038602UZQLZ2UI

```
PayPal\Api\Plan Object
(
    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
        (
            [id] => P-15T61220BN038602UZQLZ2UI
            [state] => ACTIVE
            [name] => Family plan monthly fathomreads
            [description] => Famaliy plan monthly
            [type] => INFINITE
            [payment_definitions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PayPal\Api\PaymentDefinition Object
                        (
                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => PD-6S8510199C217192C2GF6Z7A
                                    [name] => Regular Payments
                                    [type] => REGULAR
                                    [frequency] => Month
                                    [amount] => PayPal\Api\Currency Object
                                        (
                                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [currency] => USD
                                                    [value] => 6.60
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [cycles] => 0
                                    [frequency_interval] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [merchant_preferences] => PayPal\Api\MerchantPreferences Object
                (
                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                        (
                            [setup_fee] => PayPal\Api\Currency Object
                                (
                                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => USD
                                            [value] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                            [max_fail_attempts] => 0
                            [return_url] => http://localhost/fathomreads/paypalsuccess.php
                            [cancel_url] => http://localhost/fathomreads/paypalcancel.php
                            [auto_bill_amount] => YES
                            [initial_fail_amount_action] => CONTINUE
                        )

                )

            [create_time] => 2020-01-23T08:36:45.948Z
            [update_time] => 2020-01-23T08:36:47.640Z
            [links] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                        (
                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-15T61220BN038602UZQLZ2UI
                                    [rel] => self
                                    [method] => GET
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Show the API request and response from when you created the plan.

Comment: Hii @PrestonPHX  Please check . i have updated my question with the plan API request code and response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The old paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK does not support the new Subscriptions API. It uses billing plans for something older, which is not compatible with what you are trying to do.

The new paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK also does not yet support the new Subscriptions API.

So basically, to use the Subscriptions API from PHP, currently you need to implement direct HTTPS REST API calls (no SDK) to create the plan.

You could test with command-line `curl` or postman calls first, to confirm it works, and then write the necessary PHP function to do your own HTTPS calls to PayPal with the oauth token.